# ¿Como puedo "eliminar" labels en Swift?

Tags: swift, swift4

¿Hay alguna manera de que ocultar un *label* pero sí que ocupe el espacio en Swift?

Ósea es que si le pongo *.isHidden* se oculta pero ahí sigue, solo que no se ve... hay alguna forma de que tampoco ocupe un espacio, ósea como que se “elimine”?

Y al decir "eliminar" me refiero a que se oculte pero que también no ocupe espacio.
¿Cómo los puedo “eliminar”?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo pueden ver aquí en la segunda imagen uso el *.isHidden* para los ultimos *2 labels* pero aun me da el espacio de los *labels*, ocultos, pero están:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta removiendo de la vista label.removeFromSuperView()

Comment: me manda un error:
*Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value*

Comment: asignas algún valor al label? al hacer debug paso a paso puedes ver en dónde salta el error

Comment: Esa label tiene alguna "constraint" con respecto a las demás?O tal vex está dentro de una tableView? Tienes que explicar como está ubicada dentro de la vista, de esa forma podremos ayudarte

Comment: te recomienda que uses stackview como contenedor de los labels, para no tener que hacer modificaciones en los constraints y luego deberias de ejecutar el codigo yourlabel.removeFromSuperView().

Comment: Lo siento por no especificar, están adentro de un *tableView*, si tienen *constraints* y inicialmente obtienen el valor de "label".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende mucho de como este armada la vista, yo lo suelo hacer de esta forma:

El ejemplo es de una pantalla que tiene una imagen(`imgLogo`) y debajo un texto(`lblName`), cuando no hay logo para mostrar oculto el `imgLogo` y le activo/desactivo el constraint correspondiente al `lblName`

```
var topConstraintWithLogo : NSLayoutConstraint?
var topConstraintNoLogo : NSLayoutConstraint?    

func setupContraints(){
  //Aca creo todas las constraint, ojo que no las activo, solo las creo.
  topConstraintWithLogo = lblName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgLogo.bottomAnchor, constant: 20)
  topConstraintNoLogo = lblName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20)
}

//Con estos dos metodos muestro el logo o no, segun corresponda.
func hideLogo(){
    topConstraintWithLogo?.isActive = false
    topConstraintNoLogo?.isActive = true
    imgLogo.isHidden = true
}

func showLogo(){
    topConstraintWithLogo?.isActive = false
    topConstraintNoLogo?.isActive = true
    imgLogo.isHidden = false
}
```

Yo tengo armada toda la vista por codigo, pero si lo estas usando por xib o storyboard tambien se puede usar la misma solucion, aunque no necesitaras el metodo setupConstraints porque podes crear ambas constraint directo en el xib y luego linkearlas con `IBOutlet`

Existen otras alternativas como usar StackView o poner todo en una TableView, pero me parece que esta es mas generica y siempre podras usarla.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Si estás utilizando UIKit, podrías agregar los labels en un UIStackView. Al eliminarlos dejan de utilizar el espacio.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas fácil seria utilizar un

```
StackView vertical
```

Este al ocultarlos con la propiedad `isHidden`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un stack vertical y añadir la etiqueta dentro cuando la vallas a necesitar desde stack.addarrageSubView y cuando no la necesitas puedes removerla del stack accediendo a las arrageSubViews de stack y eliminar la etiqueta del índice correspondiente.